# Que son las entidades desconocidas en asp net core y el uso de traking en Program.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp

un cordial saludo amigos trabajando con asp net core me tope recientemente con una entidad que no podia actualizar, busque ayuda para resolverlo la situacion es que la persona que me ayudo me dijo que esta con una entidad desconectada a mi contexto y que debia decirle a entity framework que queria adjuntarla (attach) lo hice al final pero agregando la siguiente linea en program: `x.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);`

mi duda es que si alguien me podría explicar en palabras simples que son las entidades desconectadas y que hace la línea de código anterior, es beneficioso colocarlo en un entorno de producción?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagina un bloque extenso de código, tienes diversos objetos, algunos son la representación de una tabla de tu base de datos otros no lo son, agregas objetos a una colección, cambias alguna propiedad, etc. Y al final de tu código colocas `context.SaveChanges();` y todo los cambios se producen sin la necesidad de haber espedificado nada, casi "magicamente"

**¿Cómo puede saber Entity Framework que objeto actualizar/agregar/eliminar?**

Lo sabe porque EF hace un seguimientos a los objetos que le importan (Traking),  estos objetos tienen un estado:

- **Added**: Cuando hay tracking a un objeto, pero este aún no existe en la base de datos
- **Deleted**: Existe tracking y se eliminará de la base de datos
- **Detached**: La entidad no está siendo "trackeada"
- **Modified**: Existe tracking y existe en la base de datos, y será modificada
- **Unchanged**: Existe tracking y la entidad no tiene cambios

Como ya puedes ver existe un estado llamado `Detached` que es cuando EF deja de importarle los cambios que hagas a ese objeto (no hace tracking en ellos), y lo contrario a esto sería `Attached` que corresponde a los otros 4 estados. Donde tu podrías "Attachar" un nuevo objeto para que le haga seguimiento usando la función `context.Attach(entidad);`

**¿Por qué alguien modificaría los estados y/o haría un Attach de manera manual?**

Seguramente existen varias razones, en mi experiencia esto lo veo cuando se tiene 2 o más instancias del misma entidad. Cuando ocurre esto EF no sabe que actualizar y arroja un error en tiempo de ejecución. La solución propuesta mayoritariamente para este caso es quitar el Tracking a una de las entidades.

En lo personal, el 99,999% de estos casos, el problema está en un desorden en la lógica o desconocimiento de cómo funciona EF y la mejor solución pasa por hacer otros cambios en lugar de modificar los estados de la entidad.

Por otro lado:

**¿Por qué quitar el tracking a una entidad y si es beneficioso en producción?**

Mantener un estado y realizar seguimiento a cada entidad tiene un costo de performance, es que no puede ser de otra manera.

Generalmente este coste es imperceptible, pero pueden haber casos donde realizas un proceso "pesado" a estos datos transformándolos, calculando y modificando solo con fines de presentarlos al usuario de otra forma que no es la original. Es decir, no te interesa que estas modificaciones se guarden en la base de datos (estamos hablando solo de presentar datos). En este caso es válido quitar el tracking.

Otro ejemplo podría ser la creación de una API, donde solo existen métodos GET. Es decir, nuevamente es solo mostrar datos. Obviamente no tiene sentido hacer tracking, por lo que poner `x.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)` tiene mucho sentido

Fuentes:

- [Estados](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitystate?view=efcore-7.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-entitystate-detached)
- [Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/core/querying/tracking)
- [Explicit Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/explicit-tracking)

Comment: muchas gracias, quedo muy claro