# Problema al actualizar registro

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

saludos quisiera su ayuda para resolver un problema respecto a actualizar mi Objeto Student, resulta que al enviar los datos supuestamente me aparece que el registro se ha actualizado y revisando **infoStudent** recibe la informacion de **data** pero al parecer **SaveChanges()** no guarda la informacion  en la bd, el codigo es:

```
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]StudentDTO student)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return NotFound();
            Student infoStudent = await _context.Students.FindAsync(student.IdStudent);

            if (infoStudent == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "El Id ingresado de estudiante no se encuentra registrado" });
            }

            var careerExist = await _context.Careers.FindAsync(student.IdCareer);
            if (careerExist == null)
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "El Id ingresado de carrera no se encuentra registrado" });
            }

            Student data = _mapper.Map<Student>(student);
            
            infoStudent = data;
            
            
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(new { message = "Registro actualizado con exito" });

        }
        catch(Exception ex) { 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

se supone que se deberian de actualizar  pero no se porque no lo hace y se podria asignar cada propiedad del objeto pero no es la manera correcta de hacerlo  tambien adjunto la clase y el Dto

````
    [Index("IdCareer", Name = "Students_fk0")]
    public partial class Student
    {
        public Student()
        {
            Ratings = new HashSet<Rating>();
            Recordinscriptionstudents = new HashSet<Recordinscriptionstudent>();
        }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [Key]
        [Column("idStudent", TypeName = "int(11)")]
        public int IdStudent { get; set; }
        [Column("firstNames")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string FirstNames { get; set; } = null!;
        [Column("lastNames")]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string LastNames { get; set; } = null!;
        [Column("idCareer", TypeName = "int(11)")]
        public int? IdCareer { get; set; }
        [Column("cum")]
        [Precision(10, 0)]
        public decimal Cum { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        [ForeignKey("IdCareer")]
        [InverseProperty("Students")]
        public virtual Career? IdCareerNavigation { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdStudentNavigation")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Rating> Ratings { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("IdStudentNavigation")]
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<Recordinscriptionstudent> Recordinscriptionstudents { get; set; }
    }```

y el DTO:

```    public class StudentDTO
    {

        public int IdStudent { get; set; }
        public string FirstNames { get; set; } = null!;
        
        public string LastNames { get; set; } = null!;
        
        public int? IdCareer { get; set; }

        public decimal Cum { get; set; }

    }
````

espero su ayuda de como poder solucionarlo saludos....

Comment: Me parece que te falta el _context.Update(data)

Comment: me genera el siguiente error al usar el update: **The instance of entity type 'Student' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'IdStudent'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te aparece es porque no puedes trackear 2 instancias de la misma entidad al mismo tiempo, en tu caso `student` e `infoStudent`. Mas información en:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/573815/301324

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update([FromBody]StudentDTO student)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid) return NotFound();

            //Student infoStudent = await _context.Students.FindAsync(student.IdStudent); //esto tienes que eliminarlo, porque no puedes tener 2 veces la misma entidad, por eso te da error
            

            if (!_context.Students.Any(a=>a.IdStudent == student.IdStudent)) //alternativa para determinar si existe Student
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "El Id ingresado de estudiante no se encuentra registrado" });
            }

            //probablemente este cambio no es necesario, pero para mantener la misma forma
            //var careerExist = await _context.Careers.FindAsync(student.IdCareer);

            if (!_context.Students.Any(a=>a.IdStudent == student.IdStudent)) 
            {
                return BadRequest(new { message = "El Id ingresado de carrera no se encuentra registrado" });
            }

            Student data = _mapper.Map<Student>(student);
            
            _context.Update(data) 
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(new { message = "Registro actualizado con exito" });

        }
        catch(Exception ex) { 
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

Comment: muchas gracias ahora si me funciono, gracias por responder a mis dos post

Comment: muchas gracias ahora si me funciono, gracias por responder a mis dos post

Comment: @Jose No me había dado cuenta que eras la misma persona!!  Si te fijas esto tiene que ver con lo que te comentaba en el otro post. Si tu buscas el error, probablemente vas a encontrar que la solución era modificar el State (para cambiar el tracking), cuando es mucho más fácil no duplicar la Entidad, en este caso haciendo uso del `Any` en vez de traer la misma entidad para ver si existe. Recuerda que si las respuestas te fueron útiles puedes marcarlas como aceptadas. Saludos!